# Propensity Scores as Weights in Stata

Tags: stata, propensity-scores, weights

I'm attempting to implement a method whereby I calculate an alternative/counterfactual distribution of a variable using a calculated propensity score as a weight (this method stems from published work in JASA, [here](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic185351.files/BlackWhiteWealthGap.pdf)). I've calculated the propensity scores, however, I'm not sure what kind of weights I should be using (i.e. aweights, pweights, iweights, etc.).

Does anyone have experience using propensity scores as weights and if so, what would be the correct command in Stata?

Comment: Pretty sure its pweights. PS weights are akin to probability sampling weights.